# Sending an email in celery while running the rest of the method

Tags: python, email, flask, celery

Im trying to make my request to a page faster by having the send email part done through celery so that way the rest of the method can run and finish without having to wait for the email to be sent.

Ive tried using async and making a celery call before but I am unskilled and need a little help in that department

```
def checkout():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = User.get_username(session['email'])

        #todo: do the next line in celery

        send_email(username, session['email_to'])
        session['email_to'] = None
        flash('Youre request has been sent')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))

    return render_template('transaction/checkout.html')
```

send_email.py

```
def send_email(username_from, email):
    from_email = os.get('email')
    from_password = 'rnmmhgtlcaqsxows'
    to_email = os.get('email')

    subject = f'New Request from {username_from}'
    message = f"You have a request from {username_from}"

    msg = MIMEText(message, 'html')
    msg['subject'] = subject
    msg['To'] = to_email
    msg['From'] = from_email

    gmail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    gmail.ehlo()
    gmail.starttls()
    gmail.login(from_email, from_password)
    gmail.send_message(msg)
```

Comment: please fix indentation

Comment: thats a stack overflow thing. Assume its correct

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/celery/

Answer (score 0):

Imagine `send_email` is a Celery task. - It would be sufficient to have

```
send_email.apply_async()
```

in your code to put that task on the default Celery queue, and it will be picked and executed by Celery, while the rest of the code continues working.